# Exception Unhandled when adding new record to database table

Tags: c#, visual-studio

New to c#, I'm attempting to save a new record to a database table 'ProductTbl'. The program begins by running a windows form with multiple inputs, namely description, price, category and image. Then the save button is clicked which should save new record to the table. Following is the savebtn click code.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProductTbl product = new ProductTbl();

        product.Description = txtDescription.Text;

        product.Price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);

        product.Image = byteBLOBData;

        product.ProductType = (int)cboCategory.SelectedValue;

        cse.AddToProductTbl(product);

        cse.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");
    }
```

Following on from the cse.AddToProductTbl(product); tag, is this code in the database context.

```
internal void AddToProductTbl(ProductTbl product)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I'm continuously receiving the same error;

```
System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in Advance, Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you did not implement the "AddToProductTbl(ProductTbl product)" method. Implement the method.

```
internal void AddToProductTbl(ProductTbl product)
{
    //implementation for actually adding product to the product table
}
```

Make sure you implement the "SaveChanges()" method as well

Comment: How do I implement the method though? Sorry im new and unaware as to how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

@ Jacobrussell16.
For inserting and saving new records to the database table "ProductTbl", you could use the existing **Add** method(Context.TableName.Add()) to add records  and remove the AddToProductTbl(ProductTbl product) method. You can refer to the code sample below.

**Update:**

1.Add an image column to the database table and set its type to varbinary(MAX).

2. Add the pictureBox control in Form.cs[Design]  and double-click to add the pictureBox1_Click event.
3. Modify the code in the Form.cs.

The code in the Form.cs:

```
ProductTblContext cse = new ProductTblContext ();
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  ProductTbl product = new ProductTbl ();
  product.Id = int.Parse(txtId.Text);
  product.Name = txtProduct.Text;
  product.price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
  product.description = txtDescription.Text;

  product.type = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  ms.Dispose();
  product.image = ms.ToArray();

  cse. ProductTbl.Add(product);
  cse.SaveChanges();
  MessageBox.Show("record saved");
 }


 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
     openFileDialog.Filter = "@.jpg|*JPG|@.Png|*png|@Gif|*.gif|@.All files|*.*";
     DialogResult dr = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
     if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
     {
      FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
      Image im = Image.FromStream(fs);
      pictureBox1.Image = im;
     }
   }
```

The related code about ProductTblContext is as follows :

```
public partial class ProductTblContext: DbContext
{
    public ProductTblContext()
        : base("name= ProductTblContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ProductTbl> ProductTbl{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTbl>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTbl>()
            .Property(e => e.price)
            .HasPrecision(18, 0);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductTbl>()
            .Property(e => e.description)
            .IsFixedLength();
    }
}
```

The result is shown in the picture :
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, just two small problems, how would I do this with a product cbo and image input type?

Comment: Hi, @ Jacobrussell16. I have updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Hi, @Jacobrussell16. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.